# Deploy labels in docker compose not supported by AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to deploy a (simple) app stack consisting of a front-end, back-end, database and Traefik reverse proxy into AWS ECS. Everything put together in a Docker compose file.

I followed the docs at https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/ and looked up carefully the supported features here: https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-compose-features/.

Everything runs smoothly locally, incl. the Traefik configuration using labels. However, Traefik does not recognise any services in ECS (despite running with the proper role as described in https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/ecs/). I think it is because **labels** are not defined in the ECS tasks, although they should be supported. When I run `docker compose up` in the ECS context, I get

```
WARNING services.deploy.labels: unsupported attribute
```

Here is the compose file (a bit shorten):

```
version: "3"

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    networks:
      - ${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Variable not set}
      - default
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
    command:
      - --providers.ecs=true
      - --providers.ecs.clusters=mycluster
      - --providers.ecs.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label-stack`, `${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}`)
      - --providers.ecs.exposedbydefault=false
      - --accesslog
      - --log
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --api
    x-aws-role:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - "ecs:ListClusters"
          - "ecs:DescribeClusters"
          - "ecs:ListTasks"
          - "ecs:DescribeTasks"
          - "ecs:DescribeContainerInstances"
          - "ecs:DescribeTaskDefinition"
          - "ec2:DescribeInstances"
        Resource:
          - "*"
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.docker.network=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Variable not set}
        - traefik.constraint-label=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_TAG?Variable not set}
        - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
        - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.entrypoints=http
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.entrypoints=https
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.tls=true
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.tls.certresolver=le
        - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy.loadbalancer.server.port=80
        - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^https?://(www.)?(${DOMAIN?Variable not set})/(.*)
        - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://${DOMAIN?Variable not set}/$${3}
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect,${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT-5432}:5432"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1024M

  backend:
    image: '${DOCKER_IMAGE_BACKEND?Variable not set}:${TAG-latest}'
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=${DOMAIN?Variable not set}
      - SERVER_HOST=https://${DOMAIN?Variable not set}
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: backend.dockerfile
      args:
        INSTALL_DEV: ${INSTALL_DEV-"false"}
    ports:
      - "${BACKEND_PORT-8000}:8000"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1024M
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.constraint-label-stack=${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-http.rule=PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/docs`) || PathPrefix(`/redoc`)
        - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend.loadbalancer.server.port=8000

  frontend:
    image: '${DOCKER_IMAGE_FRONTEND?Variable not set}:${TAG-latest}'
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
      args:
        FRONTEND_ENV: ${FRONTEND_ENV-production}
    ports:
      - "${FRONTEND_PORT-3000}:3000"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1024M
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.constraint-label-stack=${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}
        - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-http.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)
        - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=3000


networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: ${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK_IS_EXTERNAL-true}
    name: "sg-mycluster"
```

Any hints much appreciated!

Thanks!
Jakub

Comment: Wondering if it's a bug? Indeed `service.deploy.labels` is in theory supported. You should probably open an issue here: https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues

Comment: Agree, I thought about it but was not sure whether I've done it right ;)

Comment: Already reported in https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1706 in May, added a comment there. No answers to the original issue yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [comment](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1706#issuecomment-1088688766), it has to be used at the service level (`service.labels`), not at the deploy level (`service.deploy.labels`).

so this should work for you:

```
services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    networks:
      - ${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Variable not set}
      - default
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "80:80"
    command:
      - --providers.ecs=true
      - --providers.ecs.clusters=mycluster
      - --providers.ecs.constraints=Label(`traefik.constraint-label-stack`, `${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}`)
      - --providers.ecs.exposedbydefault=false
      - --accesslog
      - --log
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --api
    x-aws-role:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - "ecs:ListClusters"
          - "ecs:DescribeClusters"
          - "ecs:ListTasks"
          - "ecs:DescribeTasks"
          - "ecs:DescribeContainerInstances"
          - "ecs:DescribeTaskDefinition"
          - "ec2:DescribeInstances"
        Resource:
          - "*"
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK?Variable not set}
      - traefik.constraint-label=${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_TAG?Variable not set}
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) || Host(`www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^https?://(www.)?(${DOMAIN?Variable not set})/(.*)
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://${DOMAIN?Variable not set}/$${3}
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-https.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-proxy-http.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect,${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-https-redirect

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT-5432}:5432"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1024M

  backend:
    image: '${DOCKER_IMAGE_BACKEND?Variable not set}:${TAG-latest}'
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=${DOMAIN?Variable not set}
      - SERVER_HOST=https://${DOMAIN?Variable not set}
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: backend.dockerfile
      args:
        INSTALL_DEV: ${INSTALL_DEV-"false"}
    ports:
      - "${BACKEND_PORT-8000}:8000"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1024M
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.constraint-label-stack=${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-http.rule=PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/docs`) || PathPrefix(`/redoc`)
      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend.loadbalancer.server.port=8000

  frontend:
    image: '${DOCKER_IMAGE_FRONTEND?Variable not set}:${TAG-latest}'
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: frontend.dockerfile
      args:
        FRONTEND_ENV: ${FRONTEND_ENV-production}
    ports:
      - "${FRONTEND_PORT-3000}:3000"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 1024M
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.constraint-label-stack=${TRAEFIK_TAG?Variable not set}
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-http.rule=PathPrefix(`/`)
      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=3000


networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: ${TRAEFIK_PUBLIC_NETWORK_IS_EXTERNAL-true}
    name: "sg-mycluster"
```